# Using an Already-Hashed Password with Django's Password Hashers

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have an API which devices authenticate against to receive a time-limited auth token. These devices will have a "remember my password" checkbox so this authentication can happen automatically.

I'm not going to store user passwords in plaintext on devices.

I can't make the token expiry time long, because the devices are presentational and customer-facing. Eventually a token will expire during time with a customer, and the device will either fail to make requests or have to pop up an auth dialog. There are acceptable workarounds to this (e.g. tokens last 2 days; require reauth every morning) but I'd first like to look at options that avoid exposing that complexity to devices.

I'd like to try storing the password on-device in a salted and hashed form<sup>1</sup>. This hashed password would be submitted in the auth request. Server-side, the API auth relies on Django's contrib.auth. The traditional password workflow is to hash the request password and compare it to the stored hash. Since I'd have an already-hashed request password, I'd need to *re*-hash the stored password before comparison.

I attempted this solution, but it seems to require modification of every password hasher. I still need to support standard password auth in non-API parts of the site, so I'd end up with doubled hashers for every hash algorithm I want to use: `BCryptPasswordHasher` / `PreHashedBCryptPasswordHasher` etc. While I only actually want to use one right now, it's not a scenario I want to leave for another developer to have to figure out when trying to add or change a hasher.

Another option to achieve "pre-hashing" is to modify django.contrib.auth, but I'd prefer not to maintain a fork of it.

I'm certain others have solved this issue before. I'm looking both for specific advice about how I might find a single point to effect a pre-hashed password comparison without nerfing regular comparison, and advice about the solution in general. If you have an alternative approach which addresses security and is sensible, I will be happy to hear it.

Cheers

1. This won't prevent naughty folk with access to the hash from authenticating against the API, but it'll protect users who use one password on many sites from being more broadly exposed.

Comment: I'm confused - you're providing a limited-time token, but you want to allow the user to store a password hash to avoid presenting a UI for getting a new token? It sounds like you're trying to add a second, unrevokable token.. which would be bad. Why can't you make the time-limit longer for the token?

Comment: A password change would 'revoke' the hashed password stored on the device. Your latter question is addressed in the third paragraph of my question. I don't like this "permanently remember my password" stuff, but it's a trade-off clients want to make.

Comment: If you allow people to authenticate using the hashed password, that hashed password in effect becomes a plaintext password.  By exposing an interface where you can authenticate with the hash, you've effectively converted your salted-hash password storage to plaintext password storage, which, I think, is a greater security problem than storing a single plaintext password in the user agent.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point @MichaelC.O'Connor. As I mention in my "footnote", the point is to prevent a pilfered password being used to log in to other services.

Comment: Heh, well I see you've accepted an answer that is basically my comment above. A password change is not "revoking" anything, since (a) users almost never do that and (b) it's still their password for other stuff (as you mentioned above).

Comment: @Hamish: your first point: frequency is irrelevant; a password change *would* be a revocation. Of course, then you need to ask if that's going to be your only way of revocation, is it going to cut it? I suspect this is what you're driving at. I think that's more of a policy question however. Your second point; this is true for storing plaintext passwords, but not hashed ones. I'm not sure to which you're referring, but thanks for the input in either case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if I understand your intent. You have an API for which you use Tokens to authenticate. The Token is obtained via password authentication at the beginning of the session. You want to enable a way to 'remember' passwords so that users don't have to login every time if that's what they prefer, but you do not want to store passwords in plain text in the device. Is that correct?

The simplest way to achieve this would be to make the Token permanent or have a very long expiry if the user selects 'remember me'. That way you can store a form of authentication on the device that is not the password.

This should work fine as long as you also do the following:

- When the user changes the password, invalidate all tokens on the server side.
- Generate tokens per device, present the user with a list of apps using tokens that can be revoked on their profile.

If you double hash passwords, you are basically creating a token anyways, but worse because it is linked to the password, and if the token is compromised, the password will have to be changed.

Comment: You've got it spot-on sid. I hadn't thought of varying the expiry time based on the 'remember me' setting; I like this idea. Keeps things simple, and makes the security/convenience tradeoff explicit. I had wanted to keep expiry times relatively short but hadn't equated that remembering passwords effectively nullifies this. I'll accept this answer if someone doesn't come along and answer the 'single rehashing point' question. Although it may regard a silly implementation, was still the more specific question. Really, I should learn to ask only one question!